How to find best-fit 1-subspace in case when the first singular value has multiplicity greater than 1?
Span of the first k right singular vectors is the best-fit k-subspace.
But what if we have a singular value that has multiplicity d greater than one, then the corresponding singular vectors are not unique (cause the corresponding singular vectors span a subspace of dimension d and any orthogonal basis of the corresponding subspace can be used as the eigenvectors or singular vectors). So if I would like to find best-fit k subspace, then the result depends on which set of right vectors I choose.
For example, if I have matrix consisting of 2d points (I wrote them in the matrix row-wise):
$$
A = 
\left(\begin{matrix}
-1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 \\
1 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
Then its singular value $\sigma = 2$ and has multiplicity of 2. Then if I want to find best-fit 1-subspace (i.e. line) for the points in the matrix, and thus I need to find first right singular vector. But the whole set of the right singular vectors is not unique (moreover, the order of the vectors can be choosen randomly).
So it could be
$$
v_1 = (1, 0)^T \\
v_2 = (0, 1)^T
$$
or
$$
v_1 = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^T \\
v_2 = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^T
$$
And subspaces spanned by $$
v_1 = (1, 0)^T 
$$ and $$
v_1 = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^T$$ are different. And also one can notice than actually subspace spanned by (1, 0) is not a best-fit 1-subspace.
What is wrong here? How to find best-fit 1-subspace in case when the first singular value has multiplicity greater than 1?

What is a best-fit $k$-subspace? You seem to believe that such a thing is necessarily unique, but whatever it is, how could it possibly be unique for e.g. the identity matrix?

A k-subspace V of R^d is a best-fit k-subspace to the points given by the rows of a matrix A iff it minimizes the sum of squared distances of the points described by the rows of A projected to this subspace. I am not sure that it is unique, but in the example I described we get a subspace (spanned by (1, 0)) which is definitely not a best-fit, because the sum of perpendicular distancies is not minimal

Actually subspace spanned by (1/sqrt(2), 1/sqrt(2)) is a best-fit as we can just plot the points and see, but I do not understand how to act in such situations in high dimensions
